# Queue for Single Server with Capacity constraints

Tags: queueing-theory

We have single server system and has a max capacity of 25 instances and each customer entering the server can occupy any number of instances(<= 25).
Now we want to know if the current capacity is sufficient on increasing the service  time or the number of customers, it follows poisson arrivals and exponential service time.

I will appreciate your comments. Thanks in advance for your advice.